# How to bring the app to front when starting 2 intents from a widget?

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, widget

I have a widget button that when pressing on it start's 2 intents. One of them is to dial a certain number and the second one is to open my app. The code I've got (see below) works as expected on Lollipop. The problem is on older versions, it dials the number and it opens the app, but it doesn't bring it to front.See my code below and thank you in advance.

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);


    }
}
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

    //the intent that opens the app
    Intent openAppIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
   // openAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.);
    //dial in the conference
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 123));

    Intent intents [] = {openAppIntent,callIntent};

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context,0, intents,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button,pendingIntent);




    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code in API 17 with a `Samsung [GT-S7582]` and it worked which older version have you tried it on ?.

However if you check the docs about `startActivities(Intent[])` which is the pendint intent you're creating with `PendingIntent.getActivities` you will notice a very important statement:

> Note that unlike that approach, generally none of the activities except the last in the array will be created at this point, but rather will be created when the user first visits them (due to pressing back from the activity on top).

What this means is that your call intent may not execute at least from my understanding basically startActivies can be used to create a synthetic back stack.

In any case wouldn't it be preferable just to launch your app pass it the phone number and your app instead launch the call intent ?

Something like

```
Intent openAppIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class)
    .setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 123));
```

and on SplashScreen

```
public void onCreate(...) {
    Uri phoneUri = getIntent().getData();

    if(phoneUri != null) {
      Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        .setData(phoneUri);
      startActivity(callIntent); 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it opens both intents. The problem is, it opens the app and it dials 123XXX, (when it dails, it closes the app) any suggestions?. Thank you in advance